# Mock function "Setup" not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am learning ASP.NE4 MVC3. And currentlyI am unable to see the function "SetUp" function for the mock class. Could anyone shed some light on this? Is this a function I must implement myself?  Thanks.

```
Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

mock. (m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }}.AsQueryable());
```

Comment: I only have `using Moq` and a reference to `Moq` and `Setup` shows up here.

Comment: I do not have a using statement for Moq, however; I do have the reference.

Comment: Add the using statement and it will show up.

Answer (score 0):

This basically defines an expectation on the `Products` property getter that the `IProductRepository` interface has. When this getter is invoked it will return the list that was specifically defined in the `Returns` method.

You don't need to implement anything. It's a unit test in which you provided a mock object for the repository in order to unit test some code that depends on it (like a Controller for example) in isolation.